# FacetGrid Legend empty

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create a seaborn FacetGrid to show the transition probabilities between clusters in some data I have. The data has a bunch of subjects and 4 clusters (so that each subject has 16 data points, one for each pair of old and new clusters). Because these are probabilities, all values that have the same old cluster (for each subject) sum to 1. I would like to show this data using a FacetGrid pointplot (or stacked barplot, but that doesn't seem possible with seaborn), such that each old cluster is a separate column, new cluster is a separate hue, and each facet shows subject vs. probability.

Here's code to generate a toy DataFrame with the same features as mine, as well as code for the facetgrid I'd like to make. However, when I do all this, the legend is empty.

```
df,index = [],0
for subj in [1,2]:
    for i,j in itertools.product(range(4),range(4)):
        df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=[index],data=dict(subject=subj,old=i,new=j,prob=[.23,.24,.26,.27][j])))
        index+=1
df = pd.concat(df)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,col='old',hue='new',margin_titles=False,legend_out=True)
g.map(sns.pointplot,'subject','prob',join=False)
g.add_legend()
```

Looking at `g._legend_data` shows that it's empty and each of the axes `get_legend_handles_labels()` functions returns nothing. What's going  on?

I can't post an image of my plot because I don't have 10 reputation; the name of the legend appears over on the far right, but nothing is in it...

**EDIT**: Additionally, I'd like to dodge the values a little, but `g.map(sns.pointplot,'subject','prob',join=False,dodge=.1)` looks the exact same as above, for a variety of different dodge values...

**EDIT 2:** So it appears that using `sns.factorplot`, instead of FacetGrid, both the legend and the dodge work. The only thing I can't do using sns.factorplot is rotate the xtick labels, but that's not working with `col_wrap` in Facet Grid anyway... Why is FacetGrid having this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you note, `factorplot` provides an easier interface to using `pointplot` and `FacetGrid` together. The reason the legend and dodging doesn't work the original way you're doing it is that setting `hue` in `FacetGrid` and setting it in `pointplot` are different. When you call `pointplot` without a `hue` variable, it doesn't know how to dodge, and it doesn't think it needs to add any legend data.

Option one would be to move where you use the `hue` variable:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,col='old', col_wrap=2)
g.map(sns.pointplot, 'subject', 'prob', 'new', dodge=.1, join=False)
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

But I can't think of any reason to use `FacetGrid` this way instead of just using `factorplot`:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="subject", y="prob", hue="new", data=df,
               col="old", col_wrap=2, size=3,
               dodge=.1, join=False)
```

[image]

So the only remaining issue is rotating the x axis tick labels. `factorplot` returns a `FacetGrid` instance, so in principle it should be easy to use further `FacetGrid` methods to tweak the plot. I suspect the problem you're getting is [this bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/464), which will be fixed in the next release. In the meantime, you can work around it like so:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="subject", y="prob", hue="new", data=df,
                   col="old", col_wrap=2, size=3,
                   dodge=.1, join=False)
for ax in g.axes:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

[image]